# Does lexicontext ios sdk provide autocomplete in utf8

Tags: ios, dictionary

Does lexicontext ios sdk provide autocomplete in utf8?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box I'm afraid.

But I think it shouldn't be too difficult to add this functionality using the dictionary's [search API](http://www.lexicontext.com/usage.html#usage-search).

```
// first obtain a reference to the dictionary
Lexicontext *dictionary = [Lexicontext sharedDictionary];

// later, given a prefix that the user typed, do something like:
NSDictionary *words = [dictionary wordsWithPrefix:prefix];
```

You should probably start offering to auto-complete for prefixes of at least 2 characters. 
Otherwise, you may get *very* long results. For example, the result for `[dictionary wordsWithPrefix:@"a"]` returns a result of about 1800 Adjectives, 400 Adverbs, 500 Verbs... and will probably be too slow :)